# Scikit pipeline with different datasets

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am wondering if it is possible to use `pipeline` in Scikit-Learn in the following way:

I want to train a model on dataset A and then make predictions with the same model but on dataset B. Then, like this, I can use `GridSearch` to search for the best parameters on pipeline using prediction of dataset B as a measure.

I know how to write a normal pipeline and use it with GridSearch, but I can't see how I can work with two datasets.

Comment: That's standard Cross-Validation. Search the docs for CV (can be done manually or automatically in GridsearchCV) oder just use cv=integer in GridSearchCV.

Comment: No, I am talking about 2 different datasets. I am trying to simulate prediction process - train on past data, predict on current data. But the "current" is in past. Like how would my model behave few months ago.